# Issues with populating a dropdown list using PHP

Tags: php

I was running into issues while trying to populate a drop-down list utilizing data from a database and had three key points as to where the issue could be. I am still new to PHP so trying to learn this in order to lock this down in my head. Here are the key lines.

```
$customerCountryCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'countryCode');
>$queryCountries = 'SELECT * FROM countries';
```

```
<label>Country Code:</label>
            <select name="countryCode">        
       <option value="<?php echo $customerCountryCode;?>"><?php echo $customerCountryCode;?></option>
      <?php foreach($countryCode as $queryCountries) : ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $customerCountryCode['countryCode'];?>"><?php echo $customerCountryCode['countryCode'];?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select> <br>
```

If you guys could help point me in a direction as to what my issue is with the dropdown list not populating with the countryCode column of the database, that would be amazing.

Comment: Instead of querying every details from the database for countries,try to query only the country code.
It would be great if you could upload the errors that you are getting as it would help to understand your problem better.

Comment: OK. I'm using ATOM IDE, so unfortunately I'm shooting blind into this. Let me try that and see.

Comment: I don’t have enough information about how `$countryCode` is created nor what it contains. I noticed that you are overwriting `$queryCountries`in the foreach loop, but that shouldn’t be a problem.

Comment: Hello @TimMorton, country code is a variable that holds a row from the table Countries, 
`$countryCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'countryCode');`

Comment: Your code is assigning `$_POST['countryCode']` to `$customerCountryCode`. That explains nothing about the creation nor content of `$countryCode`. For all I can tell, you’re try to loop on a user’s string input.